# Debugginng Java Code in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm currently debugging some java code in eclipse and have an issue with the same.

The debugging is working fine but when I want to change the code i.e. Hot Swap the Code Change without terminating the java debug session, its giving me an error namely `"<obsolete method in  <unknown declaring type>>".`

Due to this the thread gets suspended and I cannot modify code on the fly in debug mode.

How can I prevent this from happening and modify the java code without terminating the debug session in eclipse.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426650/eclipse-edit-the-source-and-continue-debugging

Comment: Is this a standalone Program or running on some app server?

Comment: @ Ali Alamiri : Thanks, Solved the issue, I was trying to debug statements in the main() method.

Answer (score -1):

The threads has been suspended due to the thread got stuck,executing thread is trying to complete the process in the  debugging server.