# Restarting Java procedure in Eclipse after editing

Tags: java, eclipse

Somehow I broke Eclipse's Hotswap Bug Fixing feature where editing the Java code, Eclipse resets the currently executing line and allows you to continue debugging...all without restarting the debugging session.  This was working perfectly a week ago.  Now when I edit and save the Java source, the debugger stays at the same line and continues running as if I didn't maky any changes.

I'm going to be embarrassed when you tell me what I'm did wrong to break this.  :-(  :-)

This is the question and answer here that asks my exact question.  Unfortunately, the answer is obsolete or at least I can't find the answer on the page.

[Eclipse :Edit the source and continue debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426650/eclipse-edit-the-source-and-continue-debugging)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more than three months, I discovered how to fix this!

I needed to turn on "Build Automatically" in the Project menu.

Once checked, the hot-restart began working and my debugging productivity increased dramatically.

[image: Project/Build Automatically]